# How can I filter outliers while keeping rows where the target variable is of a certain value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-science

I have a large dataset with 30 predictor variables and 1 target variable. The data was calculated to be very imbalanced, with 280,000 values showing false and 450 values true. I am trying to filter out the outliers based on the other 30 columns while keeping all rows where the target value is equal to 1.

```
def detect_outlier(df_in, col_name):
    for row in df_in['Class']:
        if row != 1:
            q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
            q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
            iqr = q3-q1
            fence_low  = q1-1.5*iqr
            fence_high = q3+1.5*iqr
            df_out = df_in.index[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
            return df_out

def remove(df, ls):
    ls = sorted(set(ls))
    df = df.drop(ls)
    return df

def remove(df, ls):
    ls = sorted(set(ls))
    df = df.drop(ls)
    return df
```

```
list = detect_outlier(cc_df,'Amount')
list
```

```
cc_df2 = remove(cc_df,list)
cc_df2
```

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mock dataset like that. It's not very imbalanced, but it will do in terms of calculations:

```
f_size = 3
ds_size = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.hstack((
        np.random.random(size=(ds_size, f_size)),
        np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(ds_size,)).reshape(ds_size, -1)
    )),
    columns=['f{}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(f_size)] + ['Class']
)

df[['Class', 'f1']].groupby('Class', as_index=False).count()
```

Output:

```
   Class  f1
0    0.0  53
1    1.0  47
```

Then your calculations can be modified a bit. The part with calculations of fences can be performed outside of the cycle, because they are all the same.

After that the outliers are simply the rows outside of either of calculated fences AND not belonging to class 1:

```
def detect_outlier(df_in, col_name):
    q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    fence_low  = q1 # - 1.5 * iqr
    fence_high = q3 # + 1.5 * iqr
    
    df_out = df_in.index[
        (df_in['Class'] != 1) &
        ((df_in[col_name] < fence_low) | (df_in[col_name] > fence_high))
    ]
    return df_out

def remove(df, ls):
    df = df.drop(ls)
    return df

outliers = detect_outlier(df, 'f1')
print(outliers)

remove(df, outliers) \
    [['Class', 'f1']] \
    .groupby('Class') \
    .count()
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([ 1,  4,  8, 13, 17, 18, 21, 23, 30, 34, 39, 45, 49, 50, 52, 62, 63,
            67, 69, 75, 76, 77, 78, 82, 83, 84, 90, 91, 96, 97],
           dtype='int64')

       f1
Class    
0.0    23
1.0    47
```

The number for class 1 didn't change!

I have commented out the iqr coefficients, becase they made fences too strict, no outliers were found for my simply generated dataset. They can work for yours, though.

```
    fence_low  = q1 # - 1.5 * iqr
    fence_high = q3 # + 1.5 * iqr
```